# How to get analog reading from an A3144 Hall sensor?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I once had a Joy-IT KY-024 sensor board that uses the A3141 Hall sensor to output analog and digital signals. I lost that sensor and then bought the Joy-IT KY-003 because I don't need the digital output anyways and the whole board is smaller. The KY-003 uses the A3144 which, according to the [data sheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/A3141-2-3-4-Datasheet.ashx), only has a different trigger point.

> The four basic devices (3141, 3142, 3143, and 3144) are identical
> except for magnetic switch points.

But with the KY-003 I only get an digital output which confuses me because the KY-024 has an analog output that according to the [data sheet](https://sensorkit.en.joy-it.net/index.php?title=KY-024_Linear_magnetic_Hall_Sensor) is a

> Direct measurement of the sensor unit

Even if this wouldn't be true, the only components on that board are some resistors and a comparator.

So how can I get an analog reading from the A3144, if it is possible at all?

Comment: I don't think the KY-024 uses the A3144. This page says it uses the SS49E which has analog output: https://joy-it.net/en/products/SEN-KY024LM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t modify the switch to become analog, so get the right part. But if you were to apply a coil with a triangular current of +/- 50 gauss at say 1kHz on the sensor...then. You might get a PWM output that may be LPF’d to create an analog signal.

So get the right part. You can’t make a pig “moo”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have an idea how they got the analog readings on the other sensor, especially when they don't have anything else on the board?

Comment: Lots of room inside for a different analog IC